# RobotFramework/JavaScript automated tree checkbox click and icon check with various tree element id

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, robotframework, browser-automation

I have dynamically generated tree html code like below:

```
<div class="treeDiv">
    <ul id="tree" class="ztree">
        (...)
                    <li id="tree_115" class="level2" treenode="">
                        <button id="tree_115_switch" class="level2 switch bottom_open" treenode_switch="" title="" type="button"></button>
                        <button id="tree_115_check" class="chk checkbox_false_full" onfocus="this.blur();" treenode_check="" type="button"></button>
                        <a id="tree_115_a" class="level2" title="myItem" style="" target="_blank" onclick="" treenode_a="">
                            <button id="tree_115_ico" class="ico_open" treenode_ico="" title="" type="button" style="background:url(./images/icon.png) 0 0 no-repeat;"></button>
                            <span id="tree_115_span">

                                myItem

                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul id="tree_115_ul" class="level2" style="display:block"></ul>
                    </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

And i have to automate setting true various checkboxes (in this case tree_115_check) and after that and after clicking OK button on this page and some operations, i have to check whether icon.png changed to OK.png. I have to reffer to object by its name, because before executing test i will know myItem name, but i won't know which element of the tree it will be. Do you know how to do that using RobotFramework or JavaScript? It will be simple, if i will know ID of all checkboxes, icons, etc, but how to do that when it is various and I know just, that i have to find "myItem" element of tree, its checkbox and status icon?

Thank You in advance for your support.

Comment: Can you try to re-explain what you are trying to do, I am a little confused. Cheers

Comment: I have to set tree_115_check checkbox true, but i have to locate this checkbox using "myItem" (text in the same line like this checkbox), because this item can be placed in various tree elements. After that, i have to click button with fixed name (i know how to do this) and check, whether tree_115_ico icon changed from ./images/icon.png to ./images/ok.png and i have to refer to this icon using "myItem" name again...

Code above is just a part of full tree. There are more elements dynamically generated above and below tree_115 :)